# speech to text reconize with button

Tags: c#, winforms, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am making speech to text app in C# window form it was working fine and running in visual studio but

when I click on button the button start recognizing but when I again click on the button to stop recognizing it is not stop and start recognizing until I closed the application

How can I solve this?

My code:

```
    using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public async Task RecognitionWithMicrophoneAsync()
        {

            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("key", "region");
            var stopRecognition = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
            using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config))
            {
                //var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                recognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("Say something...");
                };
                recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
                {
                    // Checks result.
                    if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={e.Result.Text}");
                        SendKeys.SendWait(e.Result.Text);

                        //tb_1.Text += result.Text;
                    }
                    else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
                    {
                     Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
                    }
                    };
                    recognizer.Canceled += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={e.Reason}");
                        if (e.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={e.ErrorCode}");
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails={e.ErrorDetails}");
                            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
                        }
                        button1.Enabled = true;
                        picture_btn.Image = Properties.Resources.green;
                        stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
                    };
                    recognizer.SessionStarted += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("\n    Session started event.");
                    };

                    recognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("\n    Session stopped event.");
                        //Console.WriteLine("\nStop recognition.");
                        stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
                    };

                    // Starts continuous recognition. Uses StopContinuousRecognitionAsync() to stop recognition.
                    await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    // Waits for completion.
                    // Use Task.WaitAny to keep the task rooted.
                    Task.WaitAny(new[] { stopRecognition.Task });

                    // Stops recognition.
                    await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }

        






        public Form1()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();
                }

                private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                }
                private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
            picture_btn.Image = Properties.Resources.red;
            picture_btn.Enabled = false;
            RecognitionWithMicrophoneAsync().Wait();
                    //if (button1.Enabled)
                    //{
                    // button1.Enabled = true;
                    // RecognitionWithMicrophoneAsync().Wait();
                    // }
                    // else
                    //{
                    // button1.Enabled = false;
                    //RecognitionWithMicrophoneAsync().Start();
                    //}

                    //Console.WriteLine("Please press enter to exit.");
                    //Console.ReadLine();
                }


            }
}
```

Comment: where did you write the code to stop recognizing?

Comment: @Chetan                                                                                                                                       recognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("\n    Session stopped event.");
                        //Console.WriteLine("\nStop recognition.");
                        stopRecognition.TrySetResult(0);
                    };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form only has a single button, then you will not be able to *click* it again if you disable the button. That is the thing about disabling it, it will stop responding to click events.

> If you want to use the `Button.Enabled` state and chain a sequence of events, then you will find it simpler to use multiple buttons, you will see this in many interface designs. You can even overlay the buttons so as to *look* like it is the *same* button, however when using overlays you would toggle the button's `Visible` state, not `Enabled`

For your commented out code to work, simply do not disable the button.
Ideally, you would have a property or field in the view model that controls the state, in WinForms we can also use the `Tag` property on a control to assign any arbitrary values we may need to keep track of state, instead of disabling the button.

> I still prefer the VM/Property for discretely storing state, but this makes for a simple low-code solution and now that you are aware of it you may find novel uses for this `Tag` property in the future.

The next issue is that we don't want to constrain the instance of `recognizer` to a single function scope, we want `recognizer` to be stored on the member so that we can interact with it from repeated entries to the button click event handler.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    var listening = (button.Tag as bool?).GetValueOrDefault();
    if(!listening)
    {
        button.Tag = true;
        button.Image = Properties.Resources.red;
        
        await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    else
    {
        button.Tag = false;
        button.Image = Properties.Resources.green;
        
        await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

The code for the rest of your form now looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

namespace SpechToTextForms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
        SpeechConfig config;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("key", "region");
            // TODO: set other configuration parameters
            recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config);

            recognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Recognizing: {0}", e.Result);
            };
            recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
            {
                // Checks result.
                if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={e.Result.Text}");
                    //SendKeys.SendWait(e.Result.Text);

                    tb_1.Text += " " + result.Text;
                }
                else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
                }
            };
            recognizer.Canceled += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={e.Reason}");
                if (e.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={e.ErrorCode}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails={e.ErrorDetails}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
                }
                picture_btn.Tag = false;
                picture_btn.Image = Properties.Resources.green;
            };
            recognizer.SessionStarted += (s, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n    Session started event.");
            };

            recognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("\n    Session stopped event.");
                //Console.WriteLine("\nStop recognition.");
                picture_btn.Tag = false;
                picture_btn.Image = Properties.Resources.green;
            };

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var button = sender as Button;
            var listening = (button.Tag as bool?).GetValueOrDefault();
            if (!listening)
            {
                button.Tag = true;
                button.Image = Properties.Resources.red;

                await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            else
            {
                button.Tag = false;
                button.Image = Properties.Resources.green;

                await recognizer.StopContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the purposes of a demo like this, I hve commented out the use of `SendKeys` as this can make a mess if you try debugging and talking at the same time, but still a bit of fun ;)